# Combining results via arithmetic mean

Tags: r, dataframe

For combining the results of different measurements, I want to calculate their arithmetic mean. Imagine the following dataset:

```
id;attribute;time
A;AB;1
B;AB;2
C;AB;3
B;AB;4
B;AB;5
A;AB;6
```

I want to combine all results with id `A` and get their mean. The expected dataset looks like the followind. Be aware, that the value of the in between attribute, is not important, I've chosen the first entry.

```
id attribute     time
A  AB            3.500000
B  AB            3.666667
C  AB            3.000000
```

The code below does the right thing, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution for this kind of problem.

```
# Read in the data
data <- data.frame(read_delim("~/...", ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE))
# Visualize head of the data
head(data)    

# Define function to calculate the mean
calculate_mean = function(data){

  # Prepare empty result data set
  result = data.frame(id=character(), 
                      attribute=character(),
                      time=integer())

  # Iterate over specified id <-- Change this one to the one you want to iterate over
  iterator = unique(data$id)

  # Fill result dataset with mean
  for(i in iterator){
    subset = subset(data, data$id == i)
    arithmetic_mean = mean(subset$time)
    result = rbind(result, data.frame(subset[1,]$id, 
                                      subset[1,]$attribute, 
                                      arithmetic_mean))
  }

  # Set colnames properly
  colnames(result) = colnames(data)

  return(result)
}    

# Call function
result = calculate_mean(data)    

# Display the result
result
```

Do you have an idea? Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Try it the [R tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org) way:

```
library(dplyr)
dfr <- read.table(text = "id;attribute;time
A;AB;1
B;AB;2
C;AB;3
B;AB;4
B;AB;5
A;AB;6", header=TRUE, sep=";")

dfr %>% group_by(id, attribute) %>% summarize(mean=mean(time))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   id [?]
      id attribute  mean
  <fctr>    <fctr> <dbl>
1      A        AB 3.500
2      B        AB 3.667
3      C        AB 3.000
```

Answer (score 1):

What your trying to do is call a group-by you want to group by the id column and the find the mean of column time in each group. I suggest you look into the [aggregate function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/aggregate.html). This function does the following: Splits the data into subsets, computes summary statistics for each, and returns the result in a convenient form.

Answer (score 0):

```
aggregate( time~ id, FUN=mean, data=yourdataframe)
```